# Using BasedOn Style with static ResourceDictionary in different Assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

**Background**

I have multiple projects in my solution and in one project I've made a static class containing a merged `ResourceDictionary`, which I use in all my other projects:

```cs
namespace GUI.Shared.Resources
{
    public static class ResourceFactory
    {
        public static ResourceDictionary _resources = null;

        public static ResourceDictionary Resources
        {
            get
            {
                if (_resources == null)
                {
                    _resources = new ResourceDictionary();
                    _resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GUI.Shared;component/Resources/VectorIcons.xaml") });
                    _resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GUI.Shared;component/Resources/ButtonStyles.xaml") });
                }

                return _resources;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

With my styles defined in the xaml files *ButtonStyles.xaml*:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="SpecialButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Normally I use the style like this:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="GUI.Modules.TextControl.Views.TextControlView"
             x:Name="TextControl"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:GUI.Shared.Resources;assembly=GUI.Shared">
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{Binding Path=[SpecialButtonStyle],  Source={x:Static resources:ResourceFactory.Resources}}">
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Problem**

Now I want to extend my style locally in a `View`. I found out that you do this by using the `BasedOn` property.

```xml
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{Binding Path=[SpecialButtonStyle],  Source={x:Static resources:ResourceFactory.Resources}}">
    
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Only my binding method is not allowed, giving the error:

> A `Binding` cannot be set on the `BasedOn` property of type `Style`. A `Binding` can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

How can I use this style from my `ResourceFactory.Resources` as a `BasedOn` style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`BasedOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?view=netcore-3.1) property is a regular CLR property, not a dependency property, which means you cannot bind it. Furthermore the indexer syntax among [other binding path constructs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-path-syntax) are only available in the `Binding` markup extension, not in `x:Static`, `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource`.

You can create your own markup extension based on the `x:Static` implementation, but that is very complex and the wrong thing to do. Instead, you should think about following a different built-in approach to your issue.

If you want to share resources, why create a static `ResourceFactory` at all? WPF already supports resource provision with the `App.xaml` resource dictionary and scoped resources within each `FrameworkElement` through the `Resources` property. Create a resource dictionary for your shared resources e.g. like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GUI.Shared;component/Resources/VectorIcons.xaml"/>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GUI.Shared;component/Resources/ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

As you can see, this is the same as your `ResourceFactory`, but easier to use. Include this dictionary into the application resources or any other resources section of any project using a [pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#local-assembly-resource-file) e.g.:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GUI.Modules.TextControl.Views.TextControlView"
             x:Name="TextControl"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:GUI.Shared.Resources;assembly=GUI.Shared">
   <UserControl.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GUI.Shared;component/Resources/SharedResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Button>
         <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource SpecialButtonStyle}">
               <!-- ...your style definition. -->
            </Style>
         </Button.Style>
      </Button>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

There is no need for `Binding` here and it is much easier to access resources this way. You can access the resources in child controls, too, because access to resources is scoped to where they are defined.

Comment: Thank you! The reason I did it this way is to be able to easily acces the dictionary from my viewmodel like `Icon = ResourceFactory.Resources[ResourceFactory.BoxIconKey] as Canvas;`. Also I didn't want to merge all the dictionaries again in each `UserControl` and I wasn't aware that I could just load the merged dictionary. I now use a hybrid, doing as you suggested in xaml and using the old trick in my viewmodels.